# Jquery code not running on test site

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the sample of code that I've concentrating on. I've tried to incorporate it with my test site and the code doesn't work. I don't understand why, in both instances I'm using the latest version of Jquery (1.5) I'm using Google's hosted Api for my test site.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#name-label').dblclick(function() {
    $("#name").val('some text');
  });
</script>

<div class="ctrlHolder">
  <label for="" id="name-label">Name</label>
  <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="textInput small" />
  <p class="formHint">The name of the item you are submitting</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you try live function http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use that function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does wrapping it in a `$(document).ready(function() {});` work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name-label').dblclick(function(){
        $("#name").val('some text');
    });
});
```

Comment: Good.  As a rule of thumb, it is best to wrap your code in a `$.ready()` function, as this will make sure the DOM is completely loaded before your code tries to execute.  What was happening before is you were trying to get a reference to the element `name-label` before it had been loaded into the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
  $('#name-label').dblclick(function(){
      $("#name").val('some text');
  });
}
```